# Creating a list of colors based upon a partition of the set {0,1,..,n-1}

Tags: python

I have a partition of the set {0,1,...,n-1} into a list of m subsets along corresponding to m colors. I need to assign each index in my set to the corresponding color.

As a simple example, if n=8 and m=3, let

```
partition=[{0,2},{1,4,6},{3,5,7}]
colors=['r','b','c']
```

I want to create the list `['r','b','r','c','b','c','b','c']`

What is the most "pythonic" way of doing this, preferably without loops?

Comment: I don't follow. What mapping are you using?

Comment: @oda, looks like they're trying to create a list that contains `'r'` at indices `0,2`, `'b'` at indices `1,4,6` and `c` at indices `3,5,7`, so each group of indices like `{1,4,6}` corresponds to a letter like `'b'`

Comment: @oda Suppose f: {0,1,...,n-1} --> {'r','b','c'} is my mapping. I want f(i)=the set in my partition to which i belongs. For example, f(0)='r' since 0 belongs to the first in the partition; f(1)='b' since 1 belongs to the second set in my partition.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: "most pythonic" or "without loops"? Which one is it? Probably can't have both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a mapping from partition to colors, sort it; then get the values:

```
d = {k:v for s, v in zip(partition, colors) for k in s}
out = [d[k] for k in sorted(d)]
```

Output:

```
['r', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go for this approach (it does involve for loops, but uses zip which is quite Pythonic):

```
n = 8

partitions = [{0,2},{1,4,6},{3,5,7}]
colors = ['r','b','c']

result = [''] * n # or result = [None] * n
for color, partition in zip(colors, partitions):
    for index in partition:
        result[index] = color
    
print(result) # prints ['r', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I'd go with `None`.

Comment: Only possible downside I see is that you do expect to know `n` beforehand (the question is unclear about that).